# Analyzing Governmental Debt

Tags: united-states, economy

When looking at the Federal debt there are a lot of ways to interpret the data.  You can look at the dollar amount which is currently ~16 trillion or you can analyze it as a percent of the GDP.  Are there other ways of interpreting debt ratios than the two mentioned? Is there a standard approach when analyzing debt at a governmental level?

Answer (score 4):

There are definitely other ways.

As any time when dealing with time series data, a good analysis would be velocity - how fast is the debt changing, and what are the rates of change and how do THOSE change.

Additional analysis is separating one-time expenditures from recurring expenditures (e.g. debt incurred as a result of paying for WWII is a one-time event, whereas debt incurred as a result of paying for  government pensions is a recurring one). This is a difficult analysis since the debt is not directly attributed to expenditures; but the math can be done (it's done for performance attribution of financial portfolios).

There are also non-financial facets of analyzing debt:

- Geopolitical implications (debt to China vs. debt held by US public vs. debt held by UK government).
- Debt reduction analysis with an eye on high level root cause (as someone wisely noted in another answer about which president had biggest debt reduction, very frequently the root causes of budgetary changes are inherited from prior administrations). For example, large scale defunding of military purchasing may reduce debt short term, but will predictably increase the debt later on when ramp-up is required.

Answer (score 1):

One way of analyzing it is by the person to whom it is owed.

- Excluding or including intra-federal government debt (e.g. the Social Security trust fund).
- Looking at debt owed to domestic bond holders v. foreign bond holders v. foreign sovereign bond holders.
- Looking at institutional investors v. individual investors.

This has relevance for foreign affairs, national security, and diplomacy.

Another way to analyze the federal debt is by maturity dates and interest rates (including inflation adjusted debt). This is pertinent to determining the impact of the federal debt on the future cash flow needs of the country.

In a related analysis, interest payments on the federal debt considered as a share of current tax receipts, current revenues, and current government spending for purposes other than interest, are all  common.

Another common exercise is to compare the national trade deficit (i.e. imports minus exports) to the annual increase or decrease in the federal debt (the two tend to be fairly similar).

The per capita federal debt and per capita interest on the federal debt are commonly analyzed.

There are also distinctions between federal government debt in the pure sense (e.g. treasury bills and bonds) and federal government debt in an expanded definition that include government owned entities (which can actually reduce the federal debt since entities like Fannie Mae and Freddie Mac also lend a lot of money). Similarly, you can look a pure net lending considering the federal debt less federal government loans to others.